# How to distinguish between types from the Qt framework and other types?

Tags: c++, qt, c++20, c++-concepts

I would like to be able to distinguish between any type from the Qt framework and another type that is unrelated to Qt. This might be any class which is derived from `QObject` and is part of the meta object system, but could also be other types such as `QString` and `QScopedPointer`.

I'm looking for a function similar to C++20's `std::same_as` concept, except rather than comparing types, I want to compare the type with its associated library.

```
std::is_part_of_framework<QString, QtFramework>() == true;
std::is_part_of_framework<std::string, QtFramework>() == false;
```

Initially, I considered some aspects of C++20's concepts and C++17's type_traits, to try and determine if the class had a member function associated with Qt, for example:
`QObject::staticMetaObject`. This is only half the battle, as some types are not associated with the meta object system, such as `QString`.

I briefly considered the idea of reflection, to determine if the object type begins with the letter 'Q'. But to my understanding, C++ does not support reflection, and this is a horribly fragile system anyway.

Comment: Should a type inheriting from a Qt type be considered a Qt type? What's the point of the type trait you want? Why not check for the traits needed in your functions/classes instead?

Comment: What about `std::derived_from<MyType, QObject> == true`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes this is generally a better way. I suppose this is mostly because I am curious if this is possible. I'd like to be able to extend this as well to exclude or include other libraries, like boost. Say, would I be able to create a generic function, which forwards its arguments to another function defined in a shared library, which can only accept types from certain frameworks.

Comment: @vahancho this works for anything derived from QObject but not anything else, for example QString.

Comment: @HarryP2023, if you need an universal solution for all Qt classes - I don't think such exists. You might want to check each of non QObject classes at compile time, though. More sophisticated solution might consider the class hierarchies: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/hierarchy.html , which will shorten the list of classes to be checked.

Comment: How much "anything else" has to really be anything? Also, can you use Qt inside a namespace? I think that in such a way ADL could be utilized.

Comment: For me this is clearly [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). So please rephrase your question and describe why you need such functionality what is actual goal not what are the means to that goal?

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to check if a type is member of the `Qt` namespace?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Types don't belong to namespaces. Names belong to namespaces. A type may well be known by multiple names in different namespaces; or by no name at all (e.g. a type of a lambda expression). When a type is supplied as, say, a template argument, there's no way for the template to know by which of its possibly many names, if any at all., the caller happened to identify it.